# check if requested file is inside a certain folder and if yes redirect to it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to check if a requested file (let's say: www.mysite.com/info.pdf) is inside a certain folder (let's say: www.mysite.com/downloads/, thus the real path would be www.mysite.com/downloads/info.pdf) and if yes, redirect to it in order to get downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure it can be done. Use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/downloads/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ downloads/$1 [L]
```

Comment: great! thanks for the quick answer and sorry I replied a bit late, just had the time to check it. how would I change this in order to let it work only for certain file types (eg. .pdf)?

Comment: Change `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ downloads/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|pdf))$ downloads/$1 [L]`